# Create curved line / circumference using SVG

Tags: svg, line, geometry

I need to create animated circumference pixel by pixel. Is there a way to create curved line or circumference using SVG and then manipulate with length and curve radius?

Comment: There's a `<circle>` element that draws circles. If that's not suitable perhaps you could explain in detail why not.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

Can I animate the process of creating of a circle?

Comment: In what way, like you'd draw it with a constant radius or expand it from a point to the radius you want. If it's the former you do it with stroke-dasharray.

Comment: Yes! I found the way: http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/